# How can I modify this JS code to just return a datetime object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code:

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
        var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
            ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
        window[ud]= function(o){
            success && success(new Date(o.datetime));

        };
    }
```

Which is part of code I had in the app before, it is not functional.

What it is supposed to do it connect to that server and get current time using JSON. I want it to just return the datetime or even better - the current EPOCH time. I am not sure how to modify it to make it work - should I just create a new date var and return it? Like,

var newDate = new Date(o.datetime)
return newDate?

The time on the website is in this object:

```
{
  "tz": "EST", 
  "hour": 19, 
  "datetime": "Sun, 04 Mar 2012 19:20:37 -0500", 
  "second": 37, 
  "error": false, 
  "minute": 20
}
```

Comment: It’s impossible to know how the JSONP works, you need to console the `o` object and see what it looks like. But if you are fine with the client timestamp, use `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: the o object is available as seen on that website in my code - it's just a simple object.

Comment: @antonpug: Post the example response from "_that website in my code_" within your answer, please, so others can see it without the need to visit the site. Without this your question is rather incomplete or even too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `o.datetime` is a valid date that the `Date` constructor can take and parse, you should be able to call the function with a callback and apply any method you like:

```
getTime(zone, function(result) {
    console.log(result.getTime()); // the timestamp, if result is a valid Date object.
});
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date